# How to convert char* argv[1] to int and print it without warning in C

Tags: c, char, int, warnings, argv

I want to convert the argv[1] to an int. But I get this warning:

```
xorcipher.c:7:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
```

And the printf display me

```
-799362156
```

if I type

```
./xorcipher 4
```

How to correct this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int key_length = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("key_length = %d", &key_length);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: & returns the address of the variable. printf("key_length = %d", key_length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the address of `key_length`, where as the error states, `printf` expects just the value. Try this:

```
printf("key_length = %d", key_length);
```

See [this tutorial](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) on C format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The type expected by `printf("%d")` is an int.
What you are giving is a pointer to int.

So you should change

```
printf("key_length = %d", &key_length);
```

to

```
printf("key_length = %d", key_length);
```